# Designated initializer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Just to confirm is that the correct way to create designated initializer in Objective-C ?

Is this the correct way to init the ivars ?

Can you suggest me what to improve ?

Person.h

```
@interface Person : NSObject 


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int age;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *sex;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int weight;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age sex:(NSString *)s;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age sex:(NSString *)s andWeight:(float)w;


@end
```

Person.m

```
@implementation Person

@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize sex = _sex;
@synthesize age = _age;
@synthesize weight = _weight;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age sex:(NSString *)s andWeight:(float)w
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        [self setName:name];
        [self setAge:age];
        [self setSex:s];
        [self setWeight:w];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age sex:(NSString *)s
{
    return [self initWithName:name age:age sex:s andWeight:0];
}

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age
{
    return [self initWithName:name age:age sex:0];
}

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    return [self initWithName:name age:0];
}

-(id)init
{
    return [self initWithName:nil];
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you call `init` then it will call all your another init methods.

Comment: A minor suggestion that has nothing to do with your question: you might want to make `sex` an enum: `typedef enum Sex { UnspecifiedSex, Male, Female } Sex;` since I doubt you'll have a lot of different values here ;-)

Comment: vikingosegundo, thank you too for suggest !

Comment: There was a minor but significant typo that I have fixed:  you need to assign the result of `[super init]` to `self` not just compare it.

Comment: @DarkDust: Your comment is the best comment ever when you say "A minor suggestion that has nothing to do with your question: you might want to make sex".

Comment: @vikingosegundo The first "with" and final "and<verb>" are recommended, but the rest of the "withs" are overly verbose. E.g. ```initWithBitmapData:bytesPerRow:size:format:colorSpace:``` from ```CIImage```

Comment: Never access your properties inside init. Access the iVars directly, since self is potentially not well formed. Do this in dealloc too. Apple clearly states this in their docs. Use _nameOfIvar to set or get your iVars, assuming you haven't changed the names in some synthesize directive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is correct in my opinion. You can improve efficiency by calling to the main init method from any other one, so you don't chain calls, but I think there are not a big difference.

Comment: I don't think you should chain the calls.

Comment: @JeremyP, I'm spaniard and my English is not very good. I say "chain" to refer a method that calls a method that calls a method and so forth. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I think it is better if each init method calls the designated initialiser directly rather than via another init method.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's a typical pattern.  The designated  initializer has all of the parameters, and the simpler initializers fill in default values.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to call `-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name age:(int)age sex:(NSString *)s andWeight:(float)w` directly from each method. It can avoid multiple extra executions.

Apple [recommends against](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6) using accessor methods in `init` or `dealloc`. You have variables like `_name` and you can use it.

Comment: I don't agree with your last sentence about using instance variables in init methods. For properties that has been defined and synthed as, for example, 'retain' I prefer objetive-c to do the work. Even more for the new declarations 'strong' or 'weak' that are managed by the compiler.

Comment: @Gabriel:  it is Apple's recommendation not to use properties in init in case the accessor methods have been overridden by a subclass.

Comment: Ah, that's right and is obvious. It would be dangerous in that case as you where using not overridden accessors. I didn't think about that case before. But then, I'm wondering how to do that in the case of ARC 'weak' or 'strong' properties. And, on the other hand, I think that even using instance variables, you will be doing a setting that can be incompatible with subclass accessors... I have to think about this for a while.

Comment: @JeremyP Actually, Apple does not explain their recommendation. At least not that I found – see link to Apple doc I added to the answer. Your point about subclass overriding is valid, but is not the only point. If Apple has further discussion, please post a link.